# Typescript: detecting missing ids or keys in arrays of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

Say I have a simple type, which represents a key of a `Thing`:

```js
type ThingKey = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

I'd like to create an entry with some metadata for each value to later iterate over it or to use it as a map:

```js
interface Thing {
  key: ThingKey
  stuff: string
  moreStuff: number
}

const things: Thing[] = [
  {
    key: "a",
    stuff: "AAA",
    moreStuff: 42,
  },
  {
    key: "b",
    stuff: "BBB",
    moreStuff: 43,
  },
  {
    key: "c",
    stuff: "CCC",
    moreStuff: 44,
  },
]

const thingByKey = _.keyBy(things, thing => thing.key);
```

All good so far, except that TypeScript does not care if my array has all three items or some are missing. My goal is to make sure that for every possible value in `ThingKey` there exists a single entry in `thigns`. How can I achieve this?

---

I know that instead of defining an array I can go for defining a map like below and then turn it into an array. However, that requires mentioning the same key twice. This is not ideal, because it causes data repetition and also allows me to accidentally create a mismatch between the key in the object key and the key in the Thing.

```
export const alternativeThingByKey: Record<ThingKey, Thing> = {
  a: {
    key: "a",
    stuff: "AAA",
    moreStuff: 42,
  },
  b: {
    key: "b",
    stuff: "BBB",
    moreStuff: 43,
  },
  c: {
    key: "b", // <-- oops
    stuff: "CCC",
    moreStuff: 44,
  },
}

export const alternativeThings = Object.values(alternativeThingByKey)
```

Comment: If you can turn the type of an object into a tuple of it's keys you might be able to achieve this? But since object keys are not indexed I don't think you can.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this automatically, but if enforcing this constraint is critical to you, you might be better off encapsulating the entire behavior into a class (and force modifications through getters and setters instead of directly accessing the array).  This, of course, depends on how else you are using this array.

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot convert a union type to a tuple type, because tuples are ordered and unions are not. You can convert a tuple to another one though ([mapped tuples](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063)):

```
type ThingKeyValues = ["a", "b", "c"];

interface Thing<K> {
    key: K
    stuff: string
    moreStuff: number
  }

type Thingify<T> = { [P in keyof T]:  Thing<T[P]> }

type Things = Thingify<ThingKeyValues> & {length: ThingKeyValues['length']}
```

Tuples support is still quite wobbly in TS, so we have to use a superfluous generic and the silly `length` union. Still, this type seems to work well:

```
// checks

const goodThings: Things =  [
  {key: "a", stuff: "AAA", moreStuff: 42,},
  {key: "b", stuff: "BBB", moreStuff: 43,},
  {key: "c", stuff: "CCC", moreStuff: 44,},
]

// doesn't check

const badThings1: Things =  [
  {key: "a", stuff: "AAA", moreStuff: 42,},
  {key: "X", stuff: "BBB", moreStuff: 43,},
  {key: "c", stuff: "CCC", moreStuff: 44,},
]

// doesn't check

const badThings2: Things =  [
  {key: "a", stuff: "AAA", moreStuff: 42,},
  {key: "b", stuff: "BBB", moreStuff: 43,},
  {key: "c", stuff: "CCC", moreStuff: 44,},
  {key: "MORE", stuff: "CCC", moreStuff: 44,},
]
```

[PG](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMDSEQDUCGAbAVwgGcoBeKAbQCIdqAaKagIwaYGNqBdAbgCg+yYBABOAMxzto8ZCgA8aAHxQA3nygaoAa0wAuKGnWbiwAmLH6TI2UY0BbAPYiIAZVPn9SAneaijAX3U+UEhYRFQEMRA5GGUKFSoABShkbUwHMVgufTDZGMpErmVA4PBpcJRSChkIqJiKjGx8ImJlADJVPAhUYDh9GvRMXEISSgByLp64Ma4SvgB6eah2OAh2LWIBdgckEygUBwcAEwHifoqqjUojFR0QfVo2EzMLJgBBD7ZHZzcX-QAWABM9H89BudwerEYzw8TAAQgivk5XO5Xv8AMwgsEaW56DhPVEPADCJKRP0JUH+-yxfC4AkWUCODhISDGwGWq3WWx2e2YOBOFwAjOdZJcqOC8Y9oRTqB83mSUX9KcDQRL7kwABoEpXUBFwhW-WEYmk4iH46U6klEg0Uqk0ukLJZMllsjlrLTc3bsvkC0WAkWoMXXU2SugW2Gyz6Mb6Ko0q7GqM0sbURvU2pXG1Uh9XUTjh17UK3po3UrOJyUAWQA8gAlACiKYLRejyMNaNLYLpQA)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enforce that all constituents of a union string literal type are set other than with your mentioned `Record<ThingKey, Thing>` solution unfortunately.

However, if you can change `ThingKey` slightly to a tuple type, `Things` can be written as a [mapped tuple type over `ThingKey`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) like this:

```
type ThingKey = ["a", "b", "c"];

interface Thing<K> {
  key: K;
  stuff: string;
  moreStuff: number;
}

// generic type parameter needed for mapped tuple type to work
type Things<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: Thing<T[K]> };

const t: Things<ThingKey> = [
  {
    key: "a",
    stuff: "AAA",
    moreStuff: 42
  },
  {
    key: "b",
    stuff: "BBB",
    moreStuff: 43
  },
  {
    key: "c",
    stuff: "CCC",
    moreStuff: 44
  }
];
```

This solution is even more strict in that the order of items in `ThingKey` has to be preserved in the mapped type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMDSERQLxQNoBEAhgQDRQEBGZFAxgQLoDcAUC8sBAE4BmRt0eMhQAeNAD4oAbxZQoAa0wAuKGlZyAzsACuPHiq1dh6qAFsA9lwgBlHXpVJtpyt1YBfNgHpPUFBCTcCLRQoJBQYERcRKYQnFxQARAAJslQPJZmRGCQSSHaYAA20KEQLCWwiKgaIjBQEAAenEhJGlBESCB4DJK4UvhoUMgKmOY8sAwqQqg1eGjdUG6sLLTmSFohk5Uo1VPomD34stJHcoogKsRkJ1BauvoUAIJPV3JyFla2dyoALABMR25SEcZK9hucKNQgaDbvYKAAhBEvV7vGx2e7fADMAKhx1BZwu9BxmjRFwAwuSkW9LKivlBvt8ASxmCwgA)